# Can the connection string on an odbcconnection be sniffed?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using an OdbcConnection to communicate with a DB2 database ex.

```
using (var conn = new ODBCConnection("Database=Database;UID=user;PWD=password"))
{
    conn.Open();
    …
}
```

I am worried that people with access to the machine may try to steal the database credentials. I have obfuscated the code but is it possible to use a packetsniffer to get the connection string? If so is there a way to protect against this?

Comment: could you use a trusted connection instead?

Comment: Use Windows authentication if you can? Someone could certainly take a process dump and view this in windbg. With some work they would be able to track down the string.

Comment: This program runs on a 200 machines, we have defined a "machine account" and our employee's user this program to do there day to day work. we can't use windows auth because the logged in users shouldn't have accsess to the database

Answer (score 0):

you can store your connecrion string in App.Config/Web.Config then you can encrypt your connection string

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/protecting-connection-strings-and-other-configuration-information-cs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: *encrypt, not hash.  If you hashed your connection string, you'd never see it again.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has access to your assembly or executable, it's possible to use [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read the intermediate language that C# gets compiled into (CIL).  Even if you obfuscate your code, it's pretty easy to retrieve String literals.

Obfuscators will typically encrypt String literals, and inject an extra method call to decrypt them before they are used.  That means it's possible to get the implementation and keys of the decryption routine, and run them yourself.

So, to answer your question, you don't even need to use a packet sniffer to get the creds, you can do it by just examining the IL.

Comment: how can i gaurd against this?

Comment: Really, the only way to avoid this is to use Integrated Windows Authentication for your database connection, since it doesn't involve storing the password anywhere in your code. It relies on the currently logged in user of the machine.

Comment: The problem is the current logged in user shouldn't have accsess to the database, they are supposed to use the program i wrote to do their job. We want them only to use the database through this program but not have accsess to it otherwise.

Comment: One option would be to fetch the database password at runtime, over HTTPS.  You could just keep it in memory at that point.  This assumes that your back end does proper authentication checks.

Comment: Storing in memory means that someone can examine memory to get the password, then.  @user889829:  Put all your functionality into stored procedures and give your users permissions to execute those stored procedures.  Then use Windows credentials.  They will still only have access to the functionality that you've created that way.